# Decomposition into spherical harmonics

Tags: vector-fields, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics

I'm trying to follow a text I found online.
The author decomposes EM fields such

$$
\mathbf{E} = \sum_{lm}\left(f_l(r) \mathbf{Y}_{lm} - i \frac{l(l+1)}{r} g_l(r) \mathbf{\Psi}_{lm} - i\left(\frac{d g_l(r)}{dr} + g_l(r) \right) \Phi_{lm}\right) e^{-i\omega t} 
$$
$$
\mathbf{B} = \sum_{lm}\left(g_l(r) \mathbf{Y}_{lm} + i \frac{l(l+1)}{r} f_l(r) \mathbf{\Psi}_{lm} + i\left(\frac{d f_l(r)}{dr} + f_l(r) \right) \Phi_{lm}\right)e^{-i\omega t} 
$$
Where the functions are defined as
$$
\mathbf{Y}_{lm} = r \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{\nabla} Y_{lm}
$$
$$
\mathbf{\Psi}_{lm} = r \mathbf{\nabla} Y_{lm}
$$
$$
\mathbf{Y}_{lm} =  Y_{lm} \mathbf{n}
$$
where $\mathbf{n}$ is the position vector $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{r}/r$, $Y_{lm}$ are the vector spherical harmonics (the arguments $\theta, \phi$ are omitted), $f_l(r),g_l(r)$ are either the spherical Bessel functions or the spherical Bessel functions dependent only on the radial coordinate and $\mathbf{\nabla}$ is the gradient.

Now the author states, that using the equations
$$
\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{E} = 0
$$
$$
\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0
$$
and by utilizing the spherical harmonics orthogonality we get
$$
f_l(r) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{d g_l(r)}{dr} = 0
$$
But this doesn't work for me , I always get
$$
\frac{dg_l(r)}{dr} + r g_l(r) = 0
$$
Could someone check the answer with me or prove me wrong?
For further reading on the functions $(\mathbf{Y},\mathbf{\Psi},\mathbf{\Phi})$ please refer [to this text](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj7hZ3_i7T3AhXpR_EDHUdeAAUQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fisica.unam.mx%2Fpersonales%2Frbarrera%2Fpdf%2Fpub%2Fint%2F29-EuroJP-6-287-85.pdf&usg=AOvVaw01z3vfTQxDRA0i2-KZnDrw).